# Search file for match and print specific line above with conditions

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Garble
Harble
Sarble
10000 998 ABCDEF
Tarble
Farble
Karble
99999
Garble Jarble
10003 123 ABC
Tarble
Farble Karble
Karble
88888
Sarble
10001 999 ABCXYZ
Garble
Garble
Farble
99999
```

I want to print any line that starts with 100 only if 99999 is found below and second match (100) exists within maximum 10 lines above first match (999999). Since "Sarble" always exists before 100 that might be a viable route aswell.

The output from above should be:

```
10000 998 ABCDEF
10001 999 ABCXYZ
```

How would one go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless this is a school assignment or something that forces you to use sed, it's a lot easier to write a quick script in the language of your choice (I'm partial to Perl for this kind of problems)

- parse line by line
- record the line number (and the line since it's the answer) of any line starting with 100
- when you encounter 9999, record its line number
- if that number - the number recorded above is 10 or less, print the line you recorded

here's an example of how to do it in Perl, I tried to make it simple to understand so that you can translate into other programming languages, but it may still look weird if you don't know Perl at all.

```
$file = "test.txt";
open IN, "<$file"  || die "Can't open $file: $!\n";
$count = 0;

while(<IN>){
  ++$count;

  if (/^100/){
    $line=$_;
    $lineNum = $count;    
  }

  if (/^9999/){
    if ($count-$lineNum <=10){
     print $line;
    }
  }
}
```

it works for me:

```
$ perl test.pl
10000 998 ABCDEF
10001 999 ABCXYZ
```

(please mark this as an accepted answer for my efforts)

Comment: And how would that look in a perl script? It's not a school assignment so any way is a good way :)

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n '/^100/,/^99999/ {
   H
   /^99999/ {
      s/.*//;x
t beg
: beg
      s/\n100\(.*\n\)\{11,\}/&/
      t
      s/^.//
      P
      }
   }' YourFile
```

Use a test to see if more than 10 with the  `{11,`.
tested with AIX so `--posix -e`for GNU sed

Concept:

1. Don't output line without express request
2. Load in the holding buffer each line between the 2 pattern (100 and 99999)
3. At end of the group (reaching line with 999999) take the holding buffer (so all the current group) into working buffer
4. If there is more than 10 `\n` between 100 and 99999 go to end of script (so no printing)
5. if not, remove first char (\n for buffer append reason) and print first line (the one with 100)
6. continue the script process (so next lines until eventually next group

Comment: Could you please add some comments to your solution to?

Comment: He he, and I was feeling bad the Perl solution was hard to understand. The concept is the same as the one I outlined. Nice bit of sed programming Neron, but I think I'll stick to my beloved Perl for anything that can't be done in a single line.